# How to dynamically update a document or field in all associated documents in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a new Firebase user. For our production project, I'm utilising Cloud Firestore. How to dynamically update a document or field in all associated documents in Firebase. Document User A, for example, has a recipe article that Document User B and Document User C have bookmarked. The recipe article has been replicated into User B & C's documents by writing the Field Map to Boomarks List. If User A modifies the recipe article in the future, he might modify the title or add a paragraph. How do I update the same article in User B's and User C's Bookmarks Lists?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the "Data Duplication" technique and that's its hardest part. your first option is to search for all places where you have duplicated a document and update them.

Another option would be to use `Collection Group` and in this case you can reach all collections that have the same name with a single fetching call, for more details:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query